# Universal cookie isn't removing the cookie from the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have the following code in my react app to remove a cookie with `universal-cookie`:

```
if (isWorkerFinished) {
  cookies.remove('token', { path: "/" });
  return <Redirect to="/" />;
}
```

When I try any API calls after this that require the token in the cookie they fail as expected however in the chrome JS console I can see that the cookie still exits:

[image]

What's going on here? Why is the cookie not deleted but the app behaving like it is deleted?

Comment: What is "universal-cookie" here? Any plugin or what?

Comment: It's a node module.